# window.location causing continuous loop using

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm attempting to append to the URL, a query string based on a particular condition. The problem I'm having is, the following code causes the page to loop continuously:

```
function taoExtendedIdleTime() {
  if (trackingJson.loginType === 'explicit') {
    var myURL = window.location;
    window.location = myURL + "&debugMode=true&setIdleTime=60000";
  } 
} 

taoExtendedIdleTime();
```

To correct this, I attempted the following, which checks if this query already exists. If not, add it:

```
function taoExtendedIdleTime() {
  if (trackingJson.loginType === 'explicit') {
    var myURL = window.location;
      if (myURL.indexOf("&debugMode=true&setIdleTime=60000") == -1) {
        window.location = myURL + "&debugMode=true&setIdleTime=60000";
      }
  } 
} 

taoExtendedIdleTime();
```

In my dev environment, this doesn't get executed at all. When I add it to Console, I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: myURL.indexOf is not a function, and references the fourth line of this snippet: if(myURL.indexOf...).

Any help/guidance you can provide is most appreciated!!

Comment: You seem to be reloading the page because trackingJson.loginType is always 'explicit', would you mind including how trackingJson object is built ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are trying to get an object. window.location will return you Location object. what you are looking for is `window.location.href` which will return url of current location.

```
function taoExtendedIdleTime() {
   if (trackingJson.loginType === 'explicit') {
       var myURL = window.location.href;       
       window.location.href = myURL + "&debugMode=true&setIdleTime=60000";
} }
taoExtendedIdleTime();
```

Comment: Clicked send too soon! 

I actually ended up changing this, but also removing it from the function, as a colleague suggested it wasn't necessary. All is working as expected!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), `window.location` is a `Location` object (not a `String`), so it doesn't have an `indexOf` method. You might be interested in its `search` property though.

Or if you wanna go cleaner, [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Example) might help.